# i am trying to get SHA1 to firebase console and when i ran gradlew signingReport on my android studio terminal an error

Tags: android, flutter, build.gradle

i am trying to add SHA1 to my firebase console and when i ran gradlew signingReport i got this error
C:\Users\23480\StudioProjects\woerrortisunmi\android\app>build.gradle

```
     C:\Users\23480\StudioProjects\woerrortisunmi\android\app>gradle signingReport

     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

     * Where:
     Build file 'C:\Users\23480\StudioProjects\woerrortisunmi\android\app\build.gradle' line72

     * What went wrong:
     A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
     > Could not find method implementation() for arguments [androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0] on 
   project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

  * Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 9s
```

this is what is in my android/app/build.gradle file

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
    localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the 
local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID 
(https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.woerrortisunmi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
```

this is what is in my is my android/build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2'
       // classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.7.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
apply plugin: "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android"
```

this is what is in my gradle-wrapper.properties file

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your android/app/build.gradle file, you should not put your implementation for browser outside dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
```

Instead, try this

```
dependencies {
    classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:30.0.2')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```